# Google Cloud Function CORBS issue

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a google cloud function to replace my PHP API's which currently connect to a third-party application to get some data and then return the data in a JSON format

The below code works when running the function locally (it returns the JSON data), however, when I deploy the function I get a CORBS issue:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://us-central1-phg-config-d47fb.cloudfunctions.net/favicon.ico with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

 response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

 if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
  /* handle preflight OPTIONS request */
  
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

  // cache preflight response for 3600 sec
  response.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  
  return response.sendStatus(204);
}

// handle the main request
//response.send("main response");

var assert = require('assert')
  var http = require('http')

  var body = '[[BODY OF REQUEST]]';

  var postRequest = {
      host: "XXX",
      path: "XXX",
      port: 6020,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {          
          'Content-Type': 'application/moca-xml'        
      }
  }; 
 

  var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res )    {

   //response.send('data returned');
    var buffer = "";
    res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; 
      
    } );
    res.on( "end", function( data ) { console.log( buffer ); 
      let xmlParser = require('xml2json');      
      response.send(xmlParser.toJson(buffer));
    } );
   

  }); 
 
  req.write( body );
  req.end();


});
```

I then thought it might be the content type being returned from the CORBS website so I added the below before outputting the content but I still get a CORBS error

```
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Is what I am trying to do possible as I am not sure this is what google cloud functions is supposed to be for i.e. reactive to events in the Google platform

Comment: well, you are setting the `res` content-type but not the `response` content-type, which I believe is what is triggering the error, maybe that is the issue, can you try setting that also?

Comment: This has not worked, I tried changing res to response as well as having both res and response set the same i.e.

Comment: res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: Do you get any other relevant logs in the cloud function?

Comment: nothing on the firebase logs for the function, just function started and function crashed events but no details

Comment: Well, this is definately some cors misconfiguration of the requests, have you tried using some library that implements cors instead of adding them manually, like [`express/cors`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)? this might fix the issue.